# Which visa is applicable to me? Visitor or Short Student Study Visa

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas, applications, study

I am in the Yacht sailing fields and currently finished my first season (10 months) here in India. I saved some money to take up a short competent crew course with RYA (Royal Yachting Association UK). The courses are conducted by UKSA which is accredited to BAC. I am also a member of RYA.

Its a recreation course of 7 day duration which includes 5 days and 5 night practical on the boat includes food and accommodation on the boat. 2 days on site for the oral exam for which food and accommodation are included in the course fee.

There is also a boat show organized by RYA in Uk which coincides with my course and it's in the same region and I also keen on visiting this show. I have a complimentary ticket for this. The course starts from 6-13 September 2019 and the boat show is from 13-22 September 2019. My main purpose is to get the course done so that the certificate will help me for promotion and finding a better opportunity here in India. I have a RYA Powerboat certificate which I did in Thailand. I also have Radio Operator Certificate GMDSS issued by MCA UK.

Looking at the above situation can anyone tell me which visa is applicable to me. **Visitor Visa** or **Short Term Student Study Visa** my main purpose of the visit is for the course.

Please help me in this regards,
Thank

Comment: @canonacer want to convert to an answer?

Comment: I think I have now done as suggested by B.Liu and Mark Mayo.But I appear to have done something to the link. Can anyone edit please?

Comment: @canonacer done.

Answer (score 3):

As your main purpose in visiting is to study, it would appear that the Short Term Student Visa is appropriate. The [guidance for the Standard Visitor Visa](https://gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) says study cannot be the main purpose of your visit.